# Klebanov-Witten and Conifold equation

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, branes

I'm a bit confused by some that is understood in the following papers: [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807080) and [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205100). I understood that there is a GLSM with fields $A_i,B_i$ with $i=1,2$ whose moduli space is the conifold described with the constraint $z_1z_2=z_3z_4$ (page 5 of [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807080)). But when I define the "mesons" $z_1=A_1B_1$ ecc, $A$s and $B$s are matrix valued fields (infact the superpotential $W$ has a trace), and so are the $z$s. So:

1. how can I interpret the conifold equation from the matrix equation $z_1z_2=z_3z_4$?
2. what tells me that the equation that I have to impose is morally $W=0$?

Answer (score 1):

1. The snippet you're looking for here is at the top of page 10.  The conifold coordinates are of course never matrix-valued.  When the $A_i$,$B_i$ are matrix-valued, the conifold coordinates are $z_i = Tr A_i B_i$.
2. I'm not sure exactly where you're referring to, but I would suppose that it's because $W$ is not renormalizable.